# Python 3.7 zlib decompressed size is smaller than compressed

Tags: python-3.x, zlib

I wrote a small python code, which is supposed to decompress a ~180Mb large binary file. The issue is that it only decompresses around 50Mb.
I wonder if anyone has came across similar, weird issue like this before, and found solution for it.

```
import zlib, sys
text = open('REG_E.rzp','rb').read()
print(sys.getsizeof(text))
# 187424785


decompressed = zlib.decompress(text)
print(sys.getsizeof(decompressed))
# 50001
```

Additional info: the first decompressed 50Mbytes are correct, and readable in hex editor. So I'm wondering, is there a limit, on how much zlib can decompress at once? I get no error messages, so I'm kinda in the dark with this.

Comment: I suspect the file was corrupted. Can you decompress it with the normal command-line utility (not python)? Does it still decompress to 50Mb?

Comment: Do you know which compression format it's using? Which program was used to create the archive in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved. The archive was composed from multiple compressed files and had to be decompressed file by file.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you're closing your files properly, so the files may not be fully being written to:

```
import zlib, sys
with open('REG_E.rzp','rb') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(sys.getsizeof(text))

decompressed = zlib.decompress(text)
print(sys.getsizeof(decompressed))

with open('cecomp.bin','wb') as f:
    f.write(decompressed)

recomp = zlib.compress(decompressed)
print(sys.getsizeof(recomp))
with open('recomp.bin','wb') as f:
    f.write(recomp)
```

Adding the `with` blocks ensures that you're closing the files (which also  ensures that you actually finish writing to disk).

Comment: File closing doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

From the file extension, it looks like it might have been compressed with [rzip](https://rzip.samba.org/), not gzip. Rzip uses bzip2, not zlib's DEFLATE. Python's zlib module probably can't read that format.